# Inaccurate close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

When opening the close dialog and selecting "off-topic", this is one of the close reasons:

> This question does not appear to be about building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities, within the scope defined in the help center.

This close reason mentions digital communities, but questions about non-digital communities are also on-topic, according to the help center.

Can the text of this close reason please be changed?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a built in default that points at a topic setting that I can't seem to find but I agree this should be changed. I'll look in to it more.

Comment: It is the description in the site switcher (at the top where there's the list of all of the sites). We need a CM to do this for us

Comment: I dropped the word "digiatal" from that site setting